# Want to convert an objective c function into Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I have an objective c function.

```
(void)_refreshUserList {
    [[VoiceMessageController sharedController].channelSwitcher.currentChannel fetchUsersWithCompletion:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {

        NSMutableArray *newUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [users enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            [newUsers addObject:obj[kVLChannelUserInfoKeyUser]];
        }];
        if (error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Users Fetching Error" message:@"Can't fetch users" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [errorAlert show];
            });
        } else {
            self.users = newUsers;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }





    }];

}
```

I need to use an equivalent `Xamarin c#` function.

The function I am trying to bind is this:

```
(void)fetchUsersWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completionHandler;
```

I am able to successfully convert it into a `Xamarin c#` method which is this:

```
void FetchUsersWithCompletion(Action`<NSArray, NSError> `completionHandler);
```

Now the problem is I am getting output as `NSArray` . How do I convert it into `NSObject`?[Attached image of the NSArray output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIfGj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I kind of figured out this one

This is my equivalent c# code :

```
void FetchUsersCompletion(NSArray[] arg1, NSError arg2)
        {
            List<string> userIds = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arg1.Length; i++)
            {
                var value = arg1[i].ValueForKey(LibraryVoiceLayer.Constants.kVLChannelUserInfoKeyUser) as VLUser;
                userIds.Add(value.Name);
            }
            MessagingCenter.Send<ChannelPage, List<string>>(channelpage, "FetchUsers", userIds);
        }
```